# Package easylist: How to move the marker (like period) from right side of number to left?

Tags: formatting, numbering, lists, easylist

I use `easylist` to create lists in a document. Normally we get a list numbering scheme like `1.` and `2.` etc. I would like to move the period symbol from the right of the number to the left like `.1` and `.2` and so on. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
& First item
&& First sub of first
&& Second sub of first
& Second item
&& First sub of second
&& Second sub of second
& Third item
&& First sub of third
&& Second sub of third
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal example introduces a `PreMark` key that inserts content *before* each level of the counter. Additionally it allows for the use of level-specific pre-marks: `PreMark1` for a pre-mark at level `1` only, `PreMark2` for a pre-mark at level `2` only, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% Update \el@PrintCounters using a global search-and-replace
\xpatchcmd*{\el@PrintCounters}% <cmd>
  {\el@ItemCounter\bgroup}% <search>
  {\el@ItemCounter\csname PreMark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\bgroup}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\el@GenericDef{PreMark}{.}% Generic pre-mark
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
  \ListProperties(Mark={})% Remove post-mark
  & First item
  && First sub of first
  && Second sub of first
  & Second item
  && First sub of second
  && Second sub of second
  & Third item
  && First sub of third
  && Second sub of third
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! This works thank you! However when I typed `PreMark1=.` and `PreMark2=.` into the arguments for easylist, it did not work. Instead, it looked like `.1  PreMark1=.  Start of paragraph...`

Comment: @Prevost: I can't replicate your problem. [Here is an example of what I tried that worked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JJmXo.png).

Comment: That now works for me. Not sure what I was doing wrong, I think I didn't have the `Mark={}` argument in the easylist aruments. Thanks again!

Comment: @Prevost: Yes, `Mark` is set *after* every number. Since you want a `.` *before* every number, you need to clear the `Mark={}` and just set `PreMark=.` (which would be the default in my example).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but at some expense, since the code of the package is not written with such extended flexibility in mind. (I wouldn't blame the author of the package, though, since I also have difficulties to imagine use cases with the marker before the number instead of following it.)

Here is the modified code. You have to copy the code block between `\usepackage{xpatch}` and `\makeatother` (including these lines) directly after the `\usepackage{easylist}` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd
  {\el@PrintCounters}%
  {\xdef\el@ItemCounter{\el@ItemCounter
   \bgroup
   \csname el@NumberDenotation:\csname Numbers\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\endcsname{List\the\el@ControlCounter}%
   \egroup
   \csname Mark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname}%
  }%
  {\xdef\el@ItemCounter{\el@ItemCounter
   \csname Mark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname
   \bgroup
   \csname el@NumberDenotation:\csname Numbers\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\endcsname{List\the\el@ControlCounter}%
   \egroup}%
  }{}{}
\xpatchcmd
  {\el@PrintCounters}%
  {\xdef\el@ItemCounter{\el@ItemCounter
   \bgroup
   \csname el@NumberDenotation:\csname Numbers\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\endcsname{List\the\el@ControlCounter}%
   \egroup
   \expandafter\ifx\csname FinalMark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\el@NA
     \csname Mark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname
   \else
     \csname FinalMark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname
   \fi}%
  }%
  {\xdef\el@ItemCounter{\el@ItemCounter
   \expandafter\ifx\csname FinalMark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\el@NA
     \csname Mark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname
   \else
     \csname FinalMark\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname
   \fi
   \bgroup
   \csname el@NumberDenotation:\csname Numbers\the\el@ControlCounter\endcsname\endcsname{List\the\el@ControlCounter}%
   \egroup}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
& First item
&& First sub of first
&& Second sub of first
& Second item
&& First sub of second
&& Second sub of second
& Third item
&& First sub of third
&& Second sub of third
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]